# How to make a button that just cleans up text boxes data?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, button

How can i make a button work such that it clears up all **text boxes of pop up** at a same time ...

Is there a single line of code which can perform the above function?

I tried this

```
protected void AddNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AccountNumber.Text = null;
    AccountTitle.Text = null;
    PinNumber.Text = null;
    CreationDate.Text = null; 
    Balance.Text=null;
    AccountTitle.Text = null;
```

`}`

But is there a better way to Get all text  boxes blank ??

Comment: vote to close - absolutely zero effort in forming a tangible question; lacking context, code. Sana: read http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ and try again.

Comment: @Sana.91 What do you mean by "cleans up"?

Comment: @ChrisCannon: by clear up i mean to make the text in textboxes dis appear on a button click! ...

Comment: I have added up the code which i tried ... it worked perfectly well but i want to know if is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works if you want ALL textboxes on your page to be cleared on the click of a button:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    foreach (TextBox i in this.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList())
    {
        i.Text = null;
    }
 }
```

i'd be careful with this tho, as it will clear every textbox that is located on your page. But apart from that, this does what you asked for.

Comment: Jane Doe - I wanted to but the page is not giving me any option "Was that post useful to you" ...for any of the post :/

Comment: you should be able to check the V-sign on the top left of my answer. but doesn't matter if you cant find it, glad i helped you out!

Comment: Aaahh .. i found tat .. :p .. checked it

Answer (score 0):

Find the form it's in and call reset() function on it in JavaScript onclick of button.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "cleans up" as if default values were set using `<input value="defaultvalue">` etc. then reset would revert to default values as opposed to clearing / blanking the inputs.